# After creation of my own account in Uber developer console why i am not getting any confirmation message?

Tags: android, uber-api

I am new to android development while i integrating uber app in my application facing some issues like, After creation of  my own account in Uber developer console not getting any confirmation message?Now how can i get my app ID?

Comment: Post your code...stacktrace..

Answer (score 0):

Please register to Uber for a Rider account (https://get.uber.com/new-signup) and then with this account sign into the: https://developer.uber.com/dashboard. Create the new application and you are ready to start using Uber API. Once you create the new application - you will see your app listed on the dashboard - by clicking on your app - you will get to the app details - where you can see your application id (it is Client id on the dashboard). Once the new application is created and saved there is no specific "confirmation" - only on the top of the page, you should get "Success! Your changes have been saved." message.

For more info please follow our documentation: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/introduction.